# How should I reference conditional assets in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

To install bootstrap and have it work correctly on legacy versions of IE, you need to place this your head:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

That's fine on a static site, but how would this work in a Rails app? Do I use sprockets to do this?

I have `html5shiv.js` located at

`root/vendor/assets/javascripts/html5shiv.js`

and `respond.min.js` located at

`root/vendor/assets/javascripts/respond.js`

**How should I go about including these conditional assets?**

Answer (score 2):

In application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(html5shiv.js respond.js)
```

Then add them in your layout:

```
/[if LT IE 9]
  = javascript_include_tag 'html5shiv'
  = javascript_include_tag 'respond'
```

By the way, what about a CDN for those resources?